# Optimize code with predefined variables with same prefix

Tags: arduino, prefix

I'm well on my way on learning coding for Arduino.
For the following case I Googled my ass off, but can't find any helpful answer.
So, asking here. Maybe you can help me with some terminology to Google, or direct links where this is elaborated.

I want to compress the following code. The predefined colors have to be as they are.
All variables have the same prefix, namely `COLOR_`. Is there any way to compress the part that is in the setup?
See following link.

```
// Define the colors of remote control in RGB values
//                R    G    B
#define COLOR_0 {  0,   0,   0}
#define COLOR_1 {255,   0,   0} // Red
#define COLOR_2 {255, 160,  25} // Orange
#define COLOR_3 {255, 255,   0} // Yellow
#define COLOR_4 {127, 255, 127} // Pink
#define COLOR_5 {  0, 255,   0} // Green
#define COLOR_6 {  0, 255, 255} // Cyan
#define COLOR_7 {  0, 127, 255} // Light blue
#define COLOR_8 {  0,   0, 255} // Blue
#define COLOR_9 {191,   0, 255} // light green

uint16_t RGB_565(uint8_t red, uint8_t green, uint8_t blue){
    // 16-bit value to express the RGB565-color:
    // |R|R|R|R|R|G|G|G|G|G|G|B|B|B|B|B|
    uint16_t red_565 = red / 8;
    uint16_t green_565 = green / 4;
    uint16_t blue_565 = blue / 8;
    uint16_t mixed_565 = (red_565 << 11) | (green_565 << 5) | blue_565;
    return mixed_565;
}

void setup(){
    // Convert the preset colors to a RGB565-value
    const uint8_t tint_1[] = COLOR_1;
    uint16_t color_1 = RGB_565(tint_1[0], tint_1[1], tint_1[2]);
    const uint8_t tint_2[] = COLOR_2;
    uint16_t color_2 = RGB_565(tint_2[0], tint_2[1], tint_2[2]);
    const uint8_t tint_3[] = COLOR_3;
    uint16_t color_3 = RGB_565(tint_3[0], tint_3[1], tint_3[2]);
    const uint8_t tint_4[] = COLOR_4;
    uint16_t color_4 = RGB_565(tint_4[0], tint_4[1], tint_4[2]);
    // etc...
    // This part should be able to be compressed
}

void loop(){
    // Not relevant
}
```

Comment: why do you name it `COLOR_1` and not `RED` or `COLOR_RED`?

Comment: if you have constant colors, that you convert into RGB565, why not store those RGB565 values right away? also ask yourself why you want to "compress" your code. is there any good reason?

Comment: "Compress" it how?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
#define COLOR_1 255, 0, 0
```

Then simply call

```
RGB_565(COLOR_1);
```